# github Repository removal/deletion & github pages

Tags: github

If I remove/delete a public repository on gitHub, will it remove all of its clones as well? Secondly I want to share my gaming portfolio on github pages is there any way of doing that without having my repositorys cloned?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the local clones will only be unlinked when you delete the repository. If it was forked, one of the public forks will be the new parent directory. More information [here](https://help.github.com/articles/what-happens-to-forks-when-a-repository-is-deleted-or-changes-visibility/). I didn't quite understand the second question.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the repo from the GH site, it won't remove any clones created on local machines. It will delete everything on the site repository. You can configure GitHub Pages to publish your site's source files from any of these branches: master, gh-pages, or a /docs folder on your master branch. I'd check out [this article](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/), since it explains the details.